# Como voltar ao menu inicial do meu programa

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Galera, é o seguinte...
To fazendo um projeto para a cadeira de POO e queria que toda vez que eu escolhesse alguma opção e concluísse o formulário que está dentro das classes, eu retornasse ao menu principal, até digitar 6 e encerrar o programa. Mas toda vez que eu inicializo o programa e escolho a opção 1, por exemplo, quando termino o formulário o programa me manda para a outra opção, ou seja, a opção 2, e não retorna ao menu principal. Como eu posso fazer para voltar ao menu principal logo após escolher uma das opções?

```
public class Menu {

public void menuInicial() {

    int opcao = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    InserirCliente inserirCliente = new InserirCliente();
    InserirFuncionario inserirFuncionario = new InserirFuncionario();
    InserirEstoque inserirEstoque = new InserirEstoque();
    InserirAgendamento inserirAgendamento = new InserirAgendamento();
    BuscarAgendamento buscarAgendamento = new BuscarAgendamento();
    Main main = new Main();
    Cliente cliente = new Cliente();

    do {

        System.out.println("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
        System.out.println("                 BARBEARIA");
        System.out.println("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
        System.out.println("\n"
                + "1 - Cadastro de Cliente.\n"
                + "2 - Cadastro de Funcionário.\n"
                + "3 - Venda de produtos.\n"
                + "4 - Agendamento de clientes.\n"
                + "5 - Estoque.\n"
                + "6 - Encerrar.");
        opcao = sc.nextInt();
        switch (opcao) {

            case 1: {
                inserirCliente.inserirCliente();
            }

            case 2: {
                inserirFuncionario.inserirFuncionario();
            }

            case 4: {
                System.out.println("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
                System.out.println("                 AGENDAMENTO");
                System.out.println("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
                System.out.println("\n"
                        + "1 - Novo agendamento.\n"
                        + "2 - Buscar agendamento.");
                int opcaoAgendamento = sc.nextInt();
                switch (opcaoAgendamento) {
                    case 1:
                        inserirAgendamento.inserirAgendamento();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        buscarAgendamento.buscarAgendamento();
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Opção inválida.");
                        break;
                }
            }

            case 5: {
                inserirEstoque.inserirEstoque();
            }

            sc.close();
        }

    } while (opcao != 6);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Adicione o `break` no final de cada `case`, menos no `case 5`. Esse comando serve para interromper o `switch` e passar o fluxo de execução para primeira instrução após o `switch`, que no seu caso é o `while`.

Para executar o método `sc.close()` no final, você pode deixar o `case 5` sem a instrução `break`, pois assim, ele será executado na sequência.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html